# Remove content limit from magento admin grid column

Tags: magento, grid, magento-1.7

How to remove content limit from grid column.i have long text to display it in grid but when display it subtract the string.i want to show full text in the grid.

[image]

Comment: Check for renderer of your module for that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Found solution just add string_limit in  addcolumn or addColumnAfter function in grid.php

```
$this->addColumnAfter('addons', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Addons'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,            
            'index' => 'addons',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'string_limit'  => '500', /* added for content limit */

        ), 'billing_name');
```

Comment: Interesting to note that the default is 250 and that there is no way of disabling this. If you want an virtually unbounded string you just have to use a very large limit.